# Are there any requirements to spawn the Lord of Bells rift guardian?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are there any *hidden* requirements to get Lord of Bells as a rift guardian? I've heard gossip, that you need to get to level 10 of rift before reaching the 100% on kill-o-meter, but it doesn't sound plausible.

So is there anything more to it, or just pure luck and any rift guardian could spawn as *The Cow*?

Comment: Level 10 thing is not completely false - the cow rift is guaranteed to have 10 levels, despite guardian usually being summoned after clearing 3-6 levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lord of Bells only appears in the famous Cow Level. This level is a Nephalem Rift with a very (like very) low chance of spawning. When activating the Obelisk, one day, the level that you open, instead  of being "Bartuc's Madness" or "The Vizir's Abyss" (or whatever fancy name), will be The Cow Level. This rift is like every other (random place) however every monster that you will encounter will be a cow and the Rift Guardian will be The Lord of Bell once you reach 100% (plus the rift always contain 10 levels). I have completed more than 500 Rift without actually seeing it, some people got it after 700+ rift just by luck.

Short answer : No there isn't, just the luck of getting the Cow Level Rift.

Comment: and sometimes, like me, people get it under their 20 first rifts. don't despair! Just to add to your answer @WizLiz, the name of the cow rift is not predetermined. It could be any of the prefix + affix combinations.

Comment: @Sinity I tought it was alwyas named The Cow Level when it appeared, however since i never saw it I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, mine was named Bartuc's something actually. It has 10 levels full of cows!

Answer (score 2):

Spawned the cow level on my 77th rift, guess I'm a lucky one eh?

The level "name" is still a random generated name like all rifts, however you'll instantly notice it's full of cows.

After killing a while you'll walk into a event room similar to the Jar of Souls room. Speaking to the Ghost of the Cow King will launch the event with herds of cows spawning before you ending with the Cow Princess. 
[image: Ghost of the Cow King]
[image: Cow Princess].

Continuing through the rift levels until eventually the rift boss appears "Lord of Bells"!

[image: Lord of Bells]

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is the only accurate, documented answer here.

Comment: @TravisJ Probably some disgruntled players that envy him for having such tremendous luck

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes there is, there is only a CHANCE of appearing, after the Infernal Bovine Rifts easter egg, then it has a chance as any other rare rift....

keep in mind there is little detail known on your lord of bells, have fun hunting!

Lighty